# What does the phrase "It's tough to be let down when you don't expect sh*t" mean?

Tags: translation, quotes

Sorry for my language, but my student has just found this phrase somewhere and I'm not quite sure how to explain it.

Comment: Being “let down” means “one’s expectations were not met” (you can look up the idiom or phrasal verb “let down” in your favorite dictionary). But if your expectations were already low or not existence (didn’t expect squat), then it’s less likely or impossible for those expectations not to be met.

Answer (score 2):

As it (subtly) asks for more than a mere translation, I don't mind answering this one.

> It's tough to be let down when you don't expect sh**.

Breaking it down:

> **It's tough** = It's difficult
>   **to be let down** = to become disappointed by something
>   **when** = in this case, a copula referring to a time or situation
>   **you don't expect sh*t** = *you don't expect anything at all*

Usage of the slang term **sh*t** here is in place of *nothing*, but use of *nothing* would also not be correct due to double-negatives, so the best translation for the word **sh*t** in this case is *anything at all*, such that the phrase actually reads, in meaning:

> It's difficult to become disappointed by something when you don't expect anything at all.

Comment: That "difficult" looks a bit ambiguous and it seems to suggest rather that the situation isn't easy to get into, than that the result is hard to accept. Don't you think the point was "It's *doubly* painful to be let down when your expectations were already at rock bottom"?

Comment: @RobbieGoodwin that ... is the answer!

Comment: @RobbieGoodwin I might disagree, however plausible that is. It's more likely that the person who would say this is a jaded person for whom disappointments are so commonplace that expectations are so low, that the coping mechanism is to expect nothing to avoid further disappointment

Comment: psosuna, you're deepening a hole there and you're welcome to a referendum…

Comment: I think Robbie's answer is probably right, depending on the context. If the point was just that low expectations help avoid disappointment, it'd more likely be phrased as "It's hard to be let down...", whereas the more emotive "tough" lends me to think that's the emotional outcome: being hurt.

Comment: @SteveBennett My problem with seeing it in the "emotive" perspective is that "being let down when you have no expectations" is not a probable event -- it would be "being let down despite having no expectations", as in, hitting a new low

Comment: @RobbieGoodwin Not sure what you mean by "deepening a hole" there -- I'm not saying your interpretation is incorrect and mine is flawless, but I think this is one of those things where depending on how you read it, you'll see it in either way

Comment: @psosuna Hmm, interesting, but doesn't ring true for me. "It's tough being sacked when you don't have any savings" sounds perfectly idiomatic to me, for instance.